# Require form fields with php

Tags: php, forms, required-field

Given the following code example, what would I need to add to the check_input function so that it deals with missing / required form fields. Basically, all I am trying to do is to show the end user an error message on the top of my form that says something like "Fields marked with a * are required" if they try to submit the form without filling out all the required fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank in advance for your time.

```
 // Don't post the form until the submit button is pressed.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  echo( 
   check_input($_POST['name']) . <br> .
   check_input($_POST['city']);

}

// check_input function
function check_input($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES);
  return $data;
}
```

The Form

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="city">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: don't reinvent [FormValidator()](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html)

Comment: Read before you comment. That script does NOTHING as far as SANITIZING your inputs is concerned and there is no possible way to validate an arbitrary value such as a string which is why php does not have a filter_var VALIDATE_STRING function because it's not possible without making the script practically unusable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
// Don't post the form until the submit button is pressed.
$requiredFields = array('name', 'city');    // Add the 'name' for all required fields to this array
$errors = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    // Clean all inputs
    array_walk($_POST, 'check_input');

    // Loop over requiredFields and output error if any are empty
    foreach($requiredFields as $r) {
        if( strlen($_POST[$r]) == 0 ) {
            $errors = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Error/success check
    if( $errors == true ) {
        echo 'Fields marked with a * are required';
    }else{
        // no errors
        // ...
    }
}

// check_input function
function check_input(&$data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

PS: I noticed a quote mismatch in your form HTML. The method should read `method="post"`, not `method="post'`.

Comment: Some fields may or may not be required and the purpose is to add this information to the check_input function so I do not have need to have a bunch of checks for each field (which could total 30 or more by the time I am done)  .. thx for the catch on the typo tho.

Comment: To be honest, you really should perform specific validations - which requires some coding unfortunately.  However, if you're looking for quick-and-dirty solution I've updated my answer so that all you have to do is add the 'name' of each required field to the '$requiredFields' array and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks but where do I put the code if all the required fields are filled out. I tried adding an ELSE after the BREAK statement but it did not work.

Comment: Added '$errors' flag.  See modified code above. You can put your code in "// no errors" area.